# Unlabeled audio out port on afterglow headset

Tags: xbox-one

I have an unknown model of afterglow headset, and the audio in works fine. The problem is that there is a port labeled "xbox" and I have no clue what the size is. I can't get the audio out function to work unless I identify this port. Hopefully you guys can help me. I've attached pictures.[image: green]

The green port is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: If the 'Line In' one is a standard 3.5mm connection, the 'Xbox' one is probably a 2.5mm connection.